# PHP - Check if xsd is valid

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I am developing a xml-rpc server module and i have come to the point where i need to let user (developer using my module) validate XML against XSD. That is well documented and no problem, but i came to trouble when i try to check if XSD file is a valid XSD. I need to accomplish this internally in php, that excludes any online validators and other languages. External Modules, libraries or remote procedure calls are allowed, or maybe if this could be done by a xsd file that would check the validity of xsd itself, that would also be ok.
So here is the question:

**How can i check if XML file is a valid XSD**

Answer (score 1):

There is an .xsd for XSD, as well as an DTD - see https://www.w3.org/XML/Schema#resources

- XSD: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd
- DTD: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd

Verification can be done with `xmllint`:

```
$ xmllint --schema=/path/to/XMLSchema.xsd file.xsd
```

Comment: I made a deeper research in the meantime, and have come to the same solution. Except for verification with xmllint, because as far as i know, that is a command line tool, which would be clumsy for me, i'd have to write a separate script call it from some function, parse its output and continue. Question asked for a way to do it internally, however, that is just a minor issue, and replacement solution is well documented. So this answer is quite right, but still i'll add more descriptive later.